# Получить список задач на сегодня из списка всех задач в документе Excel

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Есть таблица (слева), где написаны все задания по проектам.

Эти задачи могут быть вразброс. К примеру, идёт список:

> 01.04.2017 Начать выполнение проекта Х
>
> 25.03.2017 Сделать отчёт за месяц

В таблице неудобно просматривать список задач на сегодня, выбирая текущую дату, поэтому было принято решение сделать отдельную таблицу, где будет формироваться список дел на сегодня.

В правой таблице текущая дата постоянно обновляется с помощью формулы *Today*.

Как сделать, чтобы список дел по этой дате автоматически вставлялся в эту таблицу? Возможно, есть решение лучше?

[image: Таблица]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить первым столбцом (перед столбцом с датой) доп. столбец с формулой (показана для строки 2):

```
=ЕСЛИ(B2=$G$1; МАКС($A$1:A1)+1)
```

где *В2* - ячейка с датой;

*$G$1* - ячейка с сегодняшней датой : *=СЕГОДНЯ()*

Формула вывода списка дел:

```
=ЕСЛИ(СТРОКА(A1)>МАКС($A$1:$A$100);"";ВПР(СТРОКА(A1);$A$1:$D$100;4;0))
```

где *$A$1:$D$100* - диапазон исходной таблицы, в столбце *А* - доп. формула, в столбце *D* - задачи.

*МАКС($A$1:$A$100)* лучше вынести в отдельную ячейку, чтобы не вычислять в каждой формуле.